# ngx-bootstrap - draggable modal opens up where it was moved

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I am using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable, to make the modal. Anyhow, i have a little problem with the modal. Every time I drag it, move it, dissmis it and then opening it again, **it opens at the position where it was moved**. Is there anyway how the window can "pop up" at the center of the screen, even if I moved it before? Thanks!

Comment: raise issue there also, they might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must add something to force Angular to re-render your modal.

As instance, you can use something like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isVisible">
  ... my modal code ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I'm assigning "isVisible = true" in the method (nodeDblclickHandle()) where I open the modal (using this.modal.show()), and setting "isVisible = false" in the method where I close the modal. The modal shows when I open it for the first time but when I close it and want to open it again, this error shows up in console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at nodeDblclickHandler (main.bundle.js:6972)